# How to print a string with a backward slash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, irb, ruby-1.9.2, backslash

I have a string `str = "xyz\123"` and I want to print it as is.

The IRB is giving me an unexpected output. Please find the same below:-

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > str = "xyz\123"
 => "xyzS" 
1.9.2p290 :004 >
```

Any ideas on how can I get IRB to print the original string i.e. "xyz\123".

Thank you..

**UPDATE** :

I tried escaping it , but it doesn't seem to be that simple for some reason. Please find below my trials with the same:

```
1.9.2p290 :004 > str = "xyz'\'123"
 => "xyz''123" 
1.9.2p290 :005 > str = "xyz'\\'123"
 => "xyz'\\'123" 
1.9.2p290 :006 > str = "xyz'\\\'123"
 => "xyz'\\'123" 
1.9.2p290 :007 >
```

Comment: "Just escape it." Or, "read a tutorial". Take a pick. You may want `.inspect` as well.

Comment: I wonder why this question was down voted..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATED answer:

escape token '\' is always working in plain ruby code, but not always working in "ruby console". so I suggest you write a unit test:

```
# escape_token_test.rb 
require 'test/unit'
class EscapeTokenTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_how_to_escape
    hi = "hi\\backslash"
    puts hi
  end 
end
```

and you will get result as:

```
hi\backslash
```

and see @pst's comment.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. It prints the backslash twice. Output: "xyz\\123"

Comment: @boddhisattva That is correct. See my comment under Hophat's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash character is an escape character. You may have seen "\n" be used to display a new line, and that is why. "\123" evaulates the ASCII code for 83, which is "S". To print a backslash use 2 backslashes. So you could use `str = "xyz\\123"`.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. It prints the backslash twice. Output: "xyz\\123"

Comment: @boddhisattva Which is *correct* because the REPL prints the `.inspect` form which, for strings is the double-quoted form that can be "eval"ed back to an equivalent of the original object. Try: `puts str` and compare.

Comment: @pst Thanks.. works now.. so its just that in Rails Console and IRB .. it wouldn't print as it does with "puts str" ?

Answer (score 0):

**How to print a backslash?**

Use 2 backslashes, e.g. `"xyz\\123"`

**Why does `"xyz\123"` evaluate to `"xyzS"`?**

In a double-quoted string, `\nnn` is an **octal escape**.

[image: Table 22.2. Substitutions in Double-Quoted Strings]

Thomas, D. (2009) Programming Ruby, p.329

So, octal 123
= (64 * 1) + (8 * 2) + 3
= decimal 83
= ASCII `S`

Comment: how does this relate to printing a backslash?

Answer (score -1):

It's simple ... try dump function:

```
mystring = %Q{"Double Quotes"}
p mystring.dump
=> "\"\\\"Double Quotes\\\"\""
p mystring
=>"\"Double Quotes\""
```